# Is there a relationship between slope of the curve $ f(x, y) = 0 $ and the partial derivative $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $?

Tags: partial-derivative, slope

Let $ f(x, y) = 0 $ define a curve. Is there any relationship between the slope of this curve and the partial derivative $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $?

For example, if $ f(x, y) = (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 - 1 $, then $ f(x, y) = 0 $ defines a circle of radius $ 1 $ centered at $ (0, 0) $.

Now $ \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x} = 2(x - 1) $.

Thus $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 $ at $ x = 1 $ and indeed we see that the circle $ f(x, y) = 0 $ also has a slope of $ 0 $ at $ x = 1 $.

Is it always true that $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 $ at $ x = a $ implies that the curve $ f(x, y) = 0 $ has a horizontal slope (slope = $ 0 $) at $ x = a $?

If yes, how can we prove it?

If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: You know that the gradient $\nabla f = (\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)$ at a point $P$ is orthogonal to the level curve of $f$ passing through $P$? (Provided $f$ is nice enough, say class $C^1$, and $\nabla f(P) \neq (0,0)$.)

Comment: In your example you mention $f(x,y) = (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 -1$. But if 
$f(x,y)=0$ then $(x-1)^2 +(y-1)^2 =1$ which is a circle centred at $(1,1)$ not $(0,0)$.

Comment: Did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

### If $f$ is nice

Suppose $f(x,y) = 0$ is locally given as the graph of some function $g$, i.e. $y = g(x)$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ are locally the same curve in the plane. This will happen whenever $f$ is nice, which in this case means $df \neq 0$ at $(x,y)$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $(x,y)$. The slope of the curve at $x$ is, by definition, $g'(x)$.

To start, we have the differential
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy
$$
On the curve $f(x, y) = 0$, $f$ is constant, so $df = 0$. Now use $y = g(x)$ to write $dy = g'(x) dx$. This gives
$$
0 = df =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} g'(x) dx
$$
That is
$$
0 = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} g'(x)\right) dx
$$
which implies
$$
0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} g'(x)
$$
Finally we solve to obtain
$$
g'(x) = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}
$$
From this formula, we see that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$, we do indeed have
$$
g'(x) = 0
$$
i.e the slope of the curve is $0$ at $x$.

### Counterexample if $f$ is not nice

Take $f(x,y) = x^3 - y^2$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0, 0) = 0$. However, if we look at the graph of $f(x,y) = 0$, we clearly see that the curve does not even have a well-defined slope at $(0, 0)$.
[image: f = 0]

I suppose we might be inclined to say that the slope really is $0$ at that point since it "approaches" $0$ from "both sides," but I think that's stretching what we mean by slope. Maybe someone else can come up with a more pathological example.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean slope (the value of the tangent line, the value of the univariate derivative)? If some function is bivariate it has no tangent line but a tangent plane.

When we take the partial derivative with respect to x we are considering that y is contant. If y is constant there is a tangent line.

The partial derivative with respect to x at some point (x,y) is the slope of the simplified univariate function.

When the partial derivative with respect to x at some line (x,y) is 0 it means that for whatever y may be when x has said value the slope is 0.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\rbf{\mathbf{R}}$The equation $f(x,y)=0$ does not always define a (smooth) curve. But let us assume, for simplicity, that it does and $f:\rbf^2\to\rbf$ is smooth and the gradient $\nabla f\ne 0$ everywhere.

It does not make sense to say "the slope of this curve". Though it makes sense to say the slope *field* on this curve or the slope of the tangent line *at a point* of this curve.

Note $f=0$ is a level curve for the function $f$. Call this curve $\gamma$.

It is [known](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Etkiffe/calc3/gradient/gradient.html) that

> At each point on this level curve, the gradient vector is perpendicular to the level curve.

In other words, if $(a,b)$ is a point on the curve, i.e., $f(a,b)=0$, and $f_x(a,b)=A$ and $f_y(a,b)=B$, then an equation to the tangent line of $\gamma$ at $(a,b)$ is
$$
A(x-a)+B(y-b)=0\;\tag{1}
$$

So if $f_x(a,b)=0$, equation (1) becomes
$$
B(y-b)=0\;.
$$
which is a horizontal line ($B\ne 0$ by our assumption).

---

[Added.] As one of the comments pointed out, in your example $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(x-1)^2-1$, the equation $f=0$ is corresponding to the circle centered at $(1,1)$, not $(0,0)$.

Moreover, it does not make sense to say the circle $f=0$ has a slope of $0$ at $x=1$. What you have instead, is that at the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and also the point $(x,y)=(1,2)$, the tangent lines to the circle both have the slope $0$.